# remove the x and y axis line from jqplot

Tags: graph, jqplot, bar-chart

I dont want the X and Y axis line on the jqplot. something like this[image]

how should i achieve this.

I tried various options of jqplot like showGrid: false etc... nothing works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this options:

```
axesDefaults: {
    rendererOptions: {
        baselineWidth: 1.5,
        drawBaseline: false
    }
},
grid: {
    drawBorder: false,
    borderWidth:0, 
    shadow:false
},
xaxis: { 
        drawMajorGridlines: false
}
```